# Prevent the screen from locking when it turns off

Tags: lock-screen

Many people have asked how to prevent their screen from turning off when they lock it or it gets locked by the timer.

I however want my screen to turn off automatically after a set period of inactivity, but not to be locked so I don't have to enter my password every time. How can I achieve this?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Pics are easily understood..

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04 go to Power → Power Saving and set the time period required then in Automatic suspend set to Off

[image]

Comment: Then my screen doesn't lock - obviously. But it also never turns off, which is, as I stated, what I want to happen after a set period of inactivity